# $so(4)=su(2)× su(2)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, lie-groups

**Modified question** There was $sl(2,\mathbb R)$ used instead of $su(2)$ in the previous version. Thanks to MattE for pointing it out.

I have seen it claimed many times that $so(4,\mathbb R)=su(2)\times su(2)$. If $C$ is a Cartan subalgebra of $so(2n)$ then the Weyl group on $so(2n)$ is generated by permutations of $(x_1,...,x_n)\in  C$ and by negations of even number of $x_i$s.
Hence, for $so(4)$, the orbit of $(x_1,x_2)\in C$ under the Weyl group action is $(x_1,x_2), 
(-x_1,-x_2), (x_2,x_1), (-x_2,-x_1).$

The Weyl group of $su(2)\times su(2)$ is the product of Weyl groups of its two components. Hence, the orbit of
$(x_1,x_2)$ in a Cartan subalgebra of $su(2)\times su(2)$ under its Weyl group action is $(x_1,x_2), (-x_1,x_2), (x_1,-x_2), (-x_1,-x_2).$

That looks like a contradiction! Where do I go wrong?
You can of course reformulate this question for $SO(4,\mathbb R)=SU(2)\times SU(2)$ or $SO(4,\mathbb C)=SL(2,\mathbb C)\times SL(2,\mathbb C).$

---

**Original question**

I have seen it claimed many times that $SO(4,\mathbb R)=SL(2,\mathbb R)\times SL(2,\mathbb R),$ However, the orbit of $(x_1,x_2)$ in a max torus of $SO(4)$ under the Weyl group action is $(x_1,x_2), (x_1^{-1},x_2^{-1}), (x_2,x_1), (x_2^{-1},x_1^{-1}),$ while the orbit of
$(x_1,x_2)$ in a max torus of $SL(2)\times SL(2)$ under the Weyl group action is $(x_1,x_2), (x_1^{-1},x_2), (x_1,x_2^{-1}), (x_1^{-1},x_2^{-1}).$

That looks like a contradiction! Where do I go wrong?

Comment: What are your $(x_1, x_2)$ for the $SO(4)$ representation?

Comment: @student One should never edit the question in such a way that renders answers extended to you look irrelevant. This wastes people's effort. I have restored the original question alongside the updated version.

Comment: Dear student, I think you should complexify your Lie algebras in order for your claimed isomorphism to be true.  Regards,

Comment: I don't understand why you think your result is a contradiction.

Comment: @MattE: I wouldn't agree, but if you are able to resolve my contradiction with $\mathbb C$ instead of $\mathbb R$ then that will do for me too!

Comment: Also, there is a question as to whether one's choice of _coordinates_ is necessarily a/the one which makes an isomorphism visible. Sometimes one proves that the "obvious" choice isn't it!

Comment: @Qiaochu: Because isomorphic Lie algebras should have W-equivariant isomorphism between their Cartan subalgebras. I guess I don't understand how the product of two Cartan (diagonal) algebras of $sl(2)$ maps onto a Cartan subalgebra of $so(4)$. It cannot be $(x_1,x_2)\to (x_1,x_2)$ map (in my above notation) since the Weyl group of $sl(2)\times sl(2)$ does not allow for permutations of $x_1,x_2$ as the one for $so(4).$

Comment: Thanks Paul. Out comments crossed.

Comment: Dear student, I dont' understand your lack of agreement.  *If* it were true that $so(4)$ were the product of $sl_2$ with itself, then by the Lie group/Lie algebra correspondence, the Lie group $SL_2(\mathbb R) \times SL_2(\mathbb R)$ would be a finite cover of $SO(4)$, which it's not.  Alternatively, $sl_2(\mathbb R) \times sl_2(\mathbb R)$ is a split Lie algebra, while $so(4)$ is not.  Am I blundering?  Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a double cover $SU(2) \times SU(2) \to SO(4)$, which induces an isomorphism of Lie algebras $so(3) \times so(3) \cong so(4)$.  One convenient way to compute this double cover is in terms of quaternions:

The unit length quaternions are isomorphic to $SU(2)$.  If we define the action
of $SU(2) \times SU(2)$ on $\mathbb H = \mathbb R^4$ (the space of quaternions) via
$(p,q)\cdot v := p v q^{-1},$ it is not hard to check that this action preserves
the norm on $\mathbb H$, and in fact induces a double cover $SU(2) \times SU(2) \to SO(4)$.

In terms of this explicit description of the double cover, it won't be hard to compute what happens on Cartan subgroups of the source and target.

Comment: Dear Matt: how do you arrive from $SU(2)\times SU(2)\rightarrow SO(4)$ to $so(3)\times so(3)\cong so(4)$? Is there a typo here?

Comment: @user32240: Dear user, there is a double cover $SU(2) \to SO(3)$, which is an isomorphism on Lie algebras.  So I wrote $so(3)$ rather than $su(2)$, just because I thought the former notation fitted in better to the context of the question.  You are free to write $su(2) \times su(2) \cong so(4)$ instead, if you prefer.   Regards,

Comment: Dear Matt: Thanks. I was confused by using type $D$ in case for type $C$. Now this is making a lot sense.

Comment: As a physicist I am often confused about group relations when the lie algebra's are isomorphic. Is there an isomorphism between the groups $SU(2) \times SU(2) \times G_1 = SO(4) \times G_2$. For some discrete groups $G_1$ and $G_2$?

Answer (score 7):

This is quite false because the LHS is compact and the RHS is not. (Where have you seen this claimed?)

The correct statement is an isomorphism of Lie algebras; $\mathfrak{so}(4) \cong \mathfrak{su}(2) \times \mathfrak{su}(2)$. This is induced by an exceptional isogeny between corresponding Lie groups, either

$$\text{SU}(2) \times \text{SU}(2) \to \text{SO}(4)$$

or

$$\text{SO}(4) \to \text{SO}(3) \times \text{SO}(3).$$

These are both double covers. The first can be constructed using quaternions and the second can be constructed using the action of $\text{SO}(4)$ on bivectors.

Comment: FYI, The OP has updated the question based on your answer. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 4):

I think I figured the relation between Cartan subalgebras of $su(2)\times su(2)$ and $so(4)$. The pair $$\left(\begin{matrix} x_1 & 0\\ 0 & -x_1\end{matrix}\right), \left(\begin{matrix} x_2 & 0\\ 0 & -x_2\end{matrix}\right)$$ in the Cartan subalgebra of $su(2)\times su(2)$ is mapped to $$\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & y_1 & 0 & 0\\ -y_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & y_2\\ 0 & 0 & -y2 & 0 \end{matrix}\right),$$ where $y_1=x_1+x_2$ and $y_2=x_1-x_2.$ This map *is* Weyl group equivariant! Thank you all who responded.

Comment: I think the $-y_1$ in the 2nd row, 2nd column should be a $0$, but other wise I think you're exactly right.